# Can I get feed data from Google Reader as JSON?

Tags: json, atom-feed, google-reader

For the unofficial Google Reader API, I can get all items for a feed in the Atom format. Are they also available in the JSON format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Reader exposes feed data as JSON at URLs of the form `http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/*escaped_feed_url*`, e.g. http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http%3A//blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/.

Comment: Thanks!! how did you find that? I tried, but it has no "summary" tag, and do you know how to change these - "published" : 1308363855, "timestampUsec" : "1308364078385650", - to Date? How to calculate? thanks

Comment: The body of the item is often in the "content" section, so you may want to look for that before you fall back on the summary. The dates are represented as seconds since the epoch (except for timestampUsec, which is in microseconds since the epoch). Your language's date/time library probably has functions for converting epoch timestamps to dates.

Comment: Hey Mihai, any idea if Google are going to block my access if I send a lot of requests?

Comment: I tried your recommended solution and it now displays a page saying that "Google Reader has been discountinued".